# How to print two 0 in my listview

Tags: java, android, arrays

Maybe It's a dumb question but I can't figure it out how to show two 00 after a :, this is what I mean:

I have two arrays:

```
int[] HoraCole = {     00, 1, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9,10,10,10,11,11,12,12,12,13,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,16,17,17,17,18,18,19,19,19,20,20,20,21,22,22,23};        
int[] MinutosCole ={   20,30,30,25,40,00,40,50,20,50,00,30,00,10,40,10,20,50,20,30,00,30,40,00,40,50,20,50,00,30,00,10,40,10,20,50,20,30,00,30,40,10,40,50,20,00,30,10};
```

And then I have an arrayadapter who takes this arrays and make a string with this format 00:00

```
    if (MinutosCole.length == HoraCole.length){        
        for (int i = 0; i < HoraCole.length; i++){  
            lista.add(HoraCole[i] + ":" + MinutosCole[i]);          
        }
    }
```

But when it's displayed the ones who have two 00 in `MinutosCole` it only shows one 0

Do you guys know why that happen?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `00` is not an int. It is a string representation of an int, or an octal writing of an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
System.out.printf("%02d%n", n);
```

and

```
String.format("%02d", minutes);
```

Comment: Thanks! I use it like this: String.format("%02d", MinutosCole[i])

Answer (score 1):

Note that 00 is interpreted as an octal notation. So the value is 0*8^0 = 0. (if you tried 08 per example, you would get a compile error).

I warn you about this because if you are doing `int a = 077;` and expect it to have the value 77 (in base 10), this is not the case and the value of `a` is actually 7*8 + 7 = 63.

If you want to pad some zeros before the numbers that are with one digit, use a formatter.

Answer (score 0):

If your values are integers, then 0000000 is always stored as a 0. If you want to print it as 00, I would suggest using String

Comment: I can't use a String Because I do math operation with the array

Comment: do the operations in integer and output in string?

Answer (score 0):

Your array is of type `int[]`. When you display an `int` it always shows as it's actual numeric value, ie. "0" instead of "00". A way around this would be to use `String.format` to pad extra zeroes when printing the integer.

Answer (score 0):

00 & 0 are same as the type you are using is int and not string.

If you define your arrays as below it'll server your purpose.

> ```
> String[] HoraCole = {     "00", "1", ...}
> String[] MinutosCole ={   "20","00","00", .. }
> ```

Other wise you can use string formatters to display 2 digit ints.
e.g.

> System.out.printf("i is %02d%n", i);

Have a look at the documentation for [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for details.